# android jack server error

Tags: android, compilation, server, android-jack-and-jill

I am triying to build AOSP Android nougat rom by using **JACK SERVER**

```
3 warnings
[ 34% 16872/49032] host Java: bouncyca...tle-bcpkix-
host_intermediates/classes)
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -
source 1.7
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 warning
[ 34% 16888/49032] Building with Jack:...l_intermediates/with-
local/classes.dex
FAILED: /bin/bash out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/core-
all_intermediates/with-local/classes.dex.rsp
Communication error with Jack server (56). Try 'jack-diagnose'
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
build/core/ninja.mk:148: recipe for target 'ninja_wrapper' failed    
make: *** [ninja_wrapper] Error 1
```

I am getting this error while compiling NOugat rom for device.
I have tried to stop, kill jack server, but it gave these error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have enough ram. I have 12G and only after setting a 20G swapfile, I was able to build with jack server. During compilation I was periodically checking available ram and I saw that jack takes around 19.8 GB...